# Customized Numbering the diagrams

Tags: numbering

I'm creating PDFs with diagrams using latex and have no problem. 
Using the below, am getting all the diagrams numbered starting from 1 in sequence.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn, oneside]{extreport}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.9in, paperheight=13.9in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{indent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
}%
[]}{\end{list}}

\font\logo=logo10
\font\sknf=SkakNew-Figurine
\font\sknfbx=SkakNew-FigurineBold
\font\skndia=SkakNew-DiagramT

\def\Metafont{\mbox{\logo METAFONT}}
\def\resetPgnTags{%
  \def\WhitePlayer{}%
  \def\BlackPlayer{}%
  \def\WhiteElo{}%
  \def\BlackElo{}%
  \def\Result{}%
  \def\Site{}%
  \def\Round{}%
  \def\Date{}%
  \def\Eco{}}

\def\whiteWins{\mbox{1--0}}
\def\blackWins{\mbox{0--1}}
\def\aDraw{\mbox{1/2--1/2}}
\def\unclearResult{$\ast$}

\def\gameHeader{}%\Result{}}

\def\rwwins{{\bfseries\ \whiteWins}}
\def\rbwins{{\bfseries\ \blackWins}}
\def\rdraw{{\bfseries\ \aDraw}}
\def\runclear{\ \unclearResult}

\def\gameskip{}
\def\headerskip{}%\smallskip}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{{\textsc{\textit{Author} - Testing}} }

\cfoot{}

\headheight = 18pt
\fancyheadoffset{50pt}

\marginparwidth = 0pt
\voffset = -40pt % altura header
\textheight = 860pt %580pt
\setlength{\columnsep}{2in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt} 

\marginparwidth = 0pt

\def\resetPgnTags{%
  \def\WhitePlayer{}%
  \def\BlackPlayer{}%
  \def\WhiteElo{}%
  \def\BlackElo{}%
  \def\Result{}%
  \def\Site{}%
  \def\Round{}%
  \def\Date{}%
  \def\Eco{}}

\def\whiteWins{\textbf\wdecisive}
\def\blackWins{\textbf\bdecisive}
\def\aDraw{\textbf\equal}
\def\unclearResult{$\ast$}

\largeboard
\showmoveron

\linespread{1}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\huge\textbf{\arabic*},start=1]
\item 
\item 
\fenboard{5Q2/8/6q1/B2Bp1k1/P1N1Pp2/5K2/8/1N4q1 w - - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\item 
\fenboard{r1b1k2r/ppppqppp/1bn2n2/4p1N1/2BPP3/1QP5/P4PPP/RNB2RK1 b kq - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\item 
\fenboard{2r3k1/4qppp/1p3n2/pNrp4/P2Qn3/1P1RN1P1/4PPKP/R7 w - - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\item 
\fenboard{8/2p3pk/r2p4/B6p/R1PpqP2/3b2PP/1Q3P2/6K1 b - - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\item 
\fenboard{2b3rk/5pr1/1p1p1n2/p1pP1q1p/P1P2P1n/1QP3PP/4RN1K/2B3RB b - - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But one special requirement is to label the diagrams with something like

> 1,2,3A,3B,3C,4,5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,6,7A,7B etc....

is there any way I can customize diagram numbering?

Thanks

Comment: Is this related to diagrams or only with enumerated lists?

Comment: could you turn your snippet into a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? It would really help :)

Comment: I pasted my entire code (with few diagrams). Now I need to customize diagram numbering like 1,2,3A,3B,3C,4,5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,6,7A,7B etc.... Another problem I face is that it always ends with a number of next diagram. How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own numbering command where you have to manually specify the number of each board, like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn, oneside]{extreport}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.9in, paperheight=13.9in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ps]{skak}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
\begin{list}{}{%
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
\setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{indent}{\parindent}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
}%
[]}{\end{list}}

\font\logo=logo10
\font\sknf=SkakNew-Figurine
\font\sknfbx=SkakNew-FigurineBold
\font\skndia=SkakNew-DiagramT

\def\Metafont{\mbox{\logo METAFONT}}
\def\resetPgnTags{%
  \def\WhitePlayer{}%
  \def\BlackPlayer{}%
  \def\WhiteElo{}%
  \def\BlackElo{}%
  \def\Result{}%
  \def\Site{}%
  \def\Round{}%
  \def\Date{}%
  \def\Eco{}}

\def\whiteWins{\mbox{1--0}}
\def\blackWins{\mbox{0--1}}
\def\aDraw{\mbox{1/2--1/2}}
\def\unclearResult{$\ast$}

\def\gameHeader{}%\Result{}}

\def\rwwins{{\bfseries\ \whiteWins}}
\def\rbwins{{\bfseries\ \blackWins}}
\def\rdraw{{\bfseries\ \aDraw}}
\def\runclear{\ \unclearResult}

\def\gameskip{}
\def\headerskip{}%\smallskip}
\frenchspacing

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{{\textsc{\textit{Author} - Testing}} }

\cfoot{}

\headheight = 18pt
\fancyheadoffset{50pt}

\marginparwidth = 0pt
\voffset = -40pt % altura header
\textheight = 860pt %580pt
\setlength{\columnsep}{2in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt} 

\marginparwidth = 0pt

\def\resetPgnTags{%
  \def\WhitePlayer{}%
  \def\BlackPlayer{}%
  \def\WhiteElo{}%
  \def\BlackElo{}%
  \def\Result{}%
  \def\Site{}%
  \def\Round{}%
  \def\Date{}%
  \def\Eco{}}

\def\whiteWins{\textbf\wdecisive}
\def\blackWins{\textbf\bdecisive}
\def\aDraw{\textbf\equal}
\def\unclearResult{$\ast$}

\largeboard
\showmoveron

\linespread{1}

\newcommand{\mynumber}[1]{{\large \textbf{#1}}\linebreak}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fenboard{5Q2/8/6q1/B2Bp1k1/P1N1Pp2/5K2/8/1N4q1 w - - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\mynumber{1}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\fenboard{r1b1k2r/ppppqppp/1bn2n2/4p1N1/2BPP3/1QP5/P4PPP/RNB2RK1 b kq - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\mynumber{2A}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\fenboard{r1b1k2r/ppppqppp/1bn2n2/4p1N1/2BPP3/1QP5/P4PPP/RNB2RK1 b kq - 0 1}
\centerline{\showboard}
\mynumber{2B}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you "I like to code". I got it done by using itemize and hardcode the label in \item line. But your solution seems even better (also worked) and will use yours. THANKS A LOT!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to number some figures with a common number (e.g. 3A, 3B, 3C), then it suggests that these three figures are closely related, so that you might want to display them together and use a common caption.
If that is the case, you could use the `subcaption` package.
Here is an example slightly adapted from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{smiley}
                \caption{A gull}
                \label{fig:gull}
        \end{subfigure}%
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{smiley}
                \caption{A tiger}
                \label{fig:tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc.
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{smiley}
                \caption{A mouse}
                \label{fig:mouse}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Pictures of animals}\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm very basic in these things and am not using "figure" at all in my code. Could you please change my code as per the subcaption and post it here? Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't successfully compile your MWE using `pdflatex` and so it is not possible for me to fix your code. Sorry. Good luck!

Comment: Can anyone else help me please? TIA